# Responsive Web Design Testing Tool is not opened on IE 8

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design, automated-tests

I'm testing a Responsive Web Design and I'm using the following tool on Windows 7:

```
http://mattkersley.com/responsive/
```

The tool is working well on Chrome and Firefox. But it is not being opened on IE8. The following pop up message was displayed:

"Internet Explorer has stopped working"

[image: The image shows the error during opening RWD tool on IE 8]

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://www.isresponsive.com/ it's work fine on IE to test responsive web design

Comment: Thanks Yahya Younes. Let me try this